# Trying to get a bot to move people to afk channel once they deafen

Tags: discord.js, discord.py

I made a post yesterday but I think accidentally used python code instead of Java, not entirely sure. I know almost nothing about coding, especially java/python so any help would be much appreciated

at this point I'm not even sure if this is java or python code, if it's java I need help with the error I'm getting if it's python can I get some help translating it to java.
thanks <3

code:

```
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
if member.VoiceState.self_deaf:
    await member.move_to(afkchannel)
```

error:

```
C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:6
@bot.event
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m
```

Answer (score 3):

> C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:6

Your file is main.js so that means that it is JavaScript.And you were trying to run python code which obviously is not compatible.

You have to delete all your Python code, and you should use:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
     let memchange = newState.member;
     if (memchange.selfDeaf){ 
        memchange.setChannel(afkchannelid);
     } else return;
});
```

Comment: I used your code and everything launched correctly but the bot does nothing when I deafen. any idea what that could be? I used console.log under the if statement but still nothing happened

Comment: did you use console log before the if statement too? just to know if the event is poping up. Use this log: `console.log( util.inspect(newState))`

Comment: I did add a console log command to see if it works and it never logged me deafening, so I think that is the issue